# STARTTLS is required to send mail but if enabled authentication fails

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using Outlook, **with another provider works fine**.

My Properties:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", protocol.toLowerCase());
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.host", host);
props.setProperty("mail.port", String.valueOf(port));
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.timeout", String.valueOf(smtpTimeout * 1000));
props.setProperty("mail.smtps.timeout", String.valueOf(smtpTimeout * 1000));
        
if (protocol.toLowerCase().equals("smtps")) {
     props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", host);
     props.setProperty("mail.smtps.port", String.valueOf(port));
     if (username != null) {
          props.setProperty("mail.smtps.user", username);
     }
     if (password != null) {
         props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
     }
} else {
     props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
     props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", String.valueOf(port));  
     if (username != null) {
         props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", username);
     }
     if (password != null) {
         //props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
     }
}
```

The error produced:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [ZRAP278CA0016.CHEP278.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

If I don't add  `mail.smtp.starttls.enable`, authentication works but can't send SMTP message.

Comment: Why you can't send SMTP message with TTLS enabled? Does it produce an error message? Or timeout?

Comment: With ttls enabled i can't authenticated.  And produce this message :        >javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [ZRAP278CA0016.CHEP278.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)

Comment: So (1) your TLS is working and (2) your authentication isn't correct. So fix that.

Comment: Without TLS authentication works. Do i need to change the provider settings?

Comment: Please: What version of Java Mail are you using? I mean: Look in the classpath for the `* mail *.jar` libraries, and post its versions.

Comment: javax.mail-1.6.2.jar @LittleSanti

Comment: javax.mail vesion seems OK. Let's try this: Maybe is it that you are using `smtps`, and so, you should set `mail.smtps.starttls.enable` and `mail.smtps.auth`? (In your code, this properties are referred to `smtp` instead of `smtps`).

Comment: Yes but i think is right because outlook uses SMTP: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:
Two things:

1. My username was without domain:
   xxxxx -->  not works
   xxxx@outlook.com ---> works

(With IMAP works without add domain)

2. Mail Object have a 'to' field doesn't match with my current email

Sorry for my bad english, thaks to all

Comment: So it was an authentication error, as I said.